# Content-type is not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, web-services

I have a webservice which returns data in json format

```
 [WebMethod]
       public string GetCustomers()
        {
            using (var documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://haseeb-pc:8080/" }.Initialize())
            {
                using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
                {
                    var query = session.Query<Customer>().Select(customer => customer).Take(20);
                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    return serializer.Serialize(query);
                }
            }
        }
```

In jQuery when i use:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

I get an error in firebug:

```
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: take.","StackTrace":........................
```

When i remove this:

```
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

My web service gave me xml like this:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"FirstName":"Human1","LastName":"Being1","Email":"myemail1","ProductInfo":{"Name":"product1","Quantity":10}}]
</string>
```

However i would like the result to be in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

when using $.ajax method of jquery for AJAX requests, shouldn't you need to provide dataType instead of contentType?

contentType is used to send data to server in specific format

dataType is used to receive data from server in specific format

something like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "json"
});
```